Introduction to Linear Algebra, Gilbert Strang, Problem 42 from section 3.5.
Choose $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$ in $R^4$. It has 24 rearrangements like $(x_2,x_1,x_3,x_4)$ and $(x_4,x_3,x_1,x_2)$. Those 24 vectors, including x itself, span a subspace S. Find a specific vectors x so that the dimension of S is three.
The solution gives the space $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=0$, but I am struggling to see exactly how we arrive there. My thoughts: The nullspace of S must has dimension 1 since S has dimension 3, which means there will be three pivot rows/columns in rref(S). I am stuck after here though.
I really appreciate any help!

For starters, a subspace does not have a nullspace. It is the nullsoace of some matrix. That is, it is the set of solutions if skme homogeneous linear system. Why just one equation here? Ah, dimension.

@TedShifrin Thanks for the correction! I get this part but the part I am missing is that why the condition is $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=0$, not any other combinations of the elements of x? Or how do we arrive at this special solution [1 1 1 1]?

You need (1) a linear homogeneous equation, so it will define a subspace; (2) just one, so the space of vectors satisfying the equation has dimension three; and which (3) is invariant under permuting the variables so that $S$ has the required form. The only such equation is $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=0$.

@ArturoMagidin Ah I see how the permutation is involved in here now. Thanks for the explanation!

Let $\mathcal{P}$ be the set of 24 permutation matrices in $\mathbb{R}^{4 \times 4}$.
The orthogonal complement of $S$ is $S^\perp = \{v : v^\top P x = 0, \forall P \in \mathcal{P}\}$.
We want this to have dimension $4-3=1$. For this, there must exist some $v_0 \ne 0$ such that $\text{span}\{v_0\} = S^\perp$.
We claim that $v_0$ must be a multiple of $(1, 1, 1, 1)$. If not, then there exists some permutation $P_0$ such that $P_0v_0 \ne v_0$. Then $P_0v_0$ is also in $S^\perp$ since $P_0^\top P$ is another permutation matrix, and $(P_0v_0)^\top P x = v_0^\top (P_0^\top P) x = 0$ for all $P \in \mathcal{P}$. But this is a contradiction because $P_0 v_0 \ne v_0$ implies $P_0 v_0 \notin \text{span}\{v_0\}$.
Thus $\text{span}\{v_0\} = \text{span}\{(1, 1, 1, 1)\}$, so $S$ consists of $x$ orthogonal to $(1, 1, 1, 1)$.
